# Can the f1, precision, accuracy and recall all have the same values?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, sentiment-analysis

I've been trying to implement a support vector machine algorithm using scikit-learn and after doing some measurements all the scores provide the same values.

```
x = df["Text"]
y = df["Mood"]

test_size = 5122

x_test = x[:-test_size]
y_test = y[:-test_size]

x_train = x[-test_size:]
y_train = y[-test_size:]

count_vect = CountVectorizer()
X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(x_train)
tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer()
X_train_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(X_train_counts)
x_test = count_vect.transform(x_test).toarray()

SVM = svm.SVC(C=1.0, kernel='linear', degree=3, gamma='auto')
SVM.fit(X_train_tfidf, y_train)
predictions_SVM = SVM.predict(x_test)

print('Accuracy score is: ', accuracy_score(y_test, predictions_SVM))
print('F1 score is: ', f1_score(y_test, predictions_SVM, average='micro'))
print('Precission score is: ', precision_score(y_test, predictions_SVM, average ='micro'))
print('Recall score is: ', recall_score(y_test, predictions_SVM, average='micro'))
```

Output:

```
Accuracy score is:  0.9687622022647403
F1 score is:  0.9687622022647403
Precission score is:  0.9687622022647403
Recall score is:  0.9687622022647403
```

Is this normal or have I made an error somewhere?

Comment: This is bad, these things can only be the same if there are only TP and in that case they will be 1 not 0.96, maybe if you weight the score somehow... can you show how does y_test and predictions_SVM looks like? are they arrays for a binary classification?

Comment: I updated the post with basically the whole code. It's a multi-class classification of labelled data for sentiment analysis. The arrays are composed of text (x) and their respective labels (y).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the documentation for these scores, it appears like they should all come out the same when you are using 'micro'.

They are all counting the fraction of times that you get the correct label.

See the examples:

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score.html

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.f1_score.html

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.precision_score.html

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.recall_score.html

In fact in the last three they all give the same example and of course get the same score.

Comment: After changing it to macro it does provide different results. I even had these tabs open and still couldn't figure it out. Is there a case where micro would be used over macro?

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Chiby This is what it says for micro: "Calculate metrics globally by counting the total true positives, false negatives and false positives." So each of those measures would produce the same result. Macro uses local mean information which is why it changes, so it depends on your use case